# Using different source control providers with different instances of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, version-control, branching-and-merging

I'm in a situation where I need to merge multiple branches of a codebase, one from TFS and one in held by git, into git. But it seems that two instances of VS share a single setting for source code provider so, for example if I want to check the history of a file in TFS prior to merging I have to manually switch providers under Tools -> Options, do my checking and switch it back.

Having to have two instances of VS running concurrently, is hard enough in terms of remembering what is what, having multiple branches is worse and having multiple source control bindings is the pits.

Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use `git-tf` to create a temporary GIT working copy of your TFS data](http://gittf.codeplex.com/), do the merge all in GIT. And then commit the changes back to TFS using git-tf if you need to update TFS as well.

Comment: Interesting. Will this allow me to see historical changes from the  TFS branch in git? This is the reason I'm working in this torturous way you see ...

Comment: You'd need to try. Since you can pull in changes changeset by changeset into a local Git repository using Git-tf, I suspect you can always make it work :).